# How to solve typesetting confusion in the section of lstlisting

Tags: listings, typography

```
\documentclass[UTF8]{ctexart}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\lstset{language=Matlab,numbers=left,frame=shadowbox,  
escapeinside='', breaklines=true}
\begin{lstlisting}
mask=abs(bestline*[data ones(size(data,1),1)]')<sigma;    
hold on;
for i=1:length(mask)
if mask(i)
stem(data(i,1),data(i,2),'fill');
end
end
xAxis = 1:6;
yAxis =  (-bestline(1)*xAxis - bestline(3) )/bestline(2);
plot(xAxis, yAxis,'r-','LineWidth',2);
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What's your question? If it's the (lack of) linebreaks, try removing the `escapeinside` option.

Comment: Remove `escapeinside=''` or set `escapeinside` to a different character.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`escapeinside=''` typesets all text enclosed in a pair of `'` in normal mode where line breaks are ignored. As you can see, you have a lot of unmatched `'`.  Removing the `escapeinside` eliminates the problem.  I have also done some visual enhancements.

N.B.: You might want to take a look at [`matlab-prettifier`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/matlab-prettifier).

```
\documentclass[UTF8]{ctexart}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\lstset{
  language=Matlab,
  numbers=left,
  frame=shadowbox,  
  %escapeinside='',
  breaklines=true,
  basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
  keywordstyle=\color{red!80!black}
}
\begin{lstlisting}
mask = abs(bestline*[data ones(size(data,1),1)]')<sigma;    
hold on;
for i=1:length(mask)
  if mask(i)
    stem(data(i,1),data(i,2),'fill');
  end
end
xAxis = 1:6;
yAxis = (-bestline(1)*xAxis - bestline(3))/bestline(2);
plot(xAxis, yAxis,'r-','LineWidth',2);
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, the reason why I add escapeinside is that I want to add some Chinese characters. And I figure out another solutions because of your answer.